# log4j : parameter appender file name

Tags: grails, groovy, log4j, grails-2.0

I use `Grails`

In my file `Config.groovy`  I create an appender as:

```
log4j = {

    appenders {
        file name:'myAppli', file:'/tmp/myAppli.log'
    }
...
}
```

Is it possible to parameter file path of my appender through data of `file.properties` ?

something like that :

```
file.properties:
myAppli.log.path=C:\\tmp\\


Config.groovy:
appenders {
    file name:'myLogs', file:myAppli.log.path + 'myLogs.log'
}
```

Comment: Did you add file.properties to `grails.config.locations` in Config.groovy?

Comment: No, what's syntaxe to add file.properties in Config.groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

myAppli.log.path should work!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's a section in the docs for this: [externalized configuration](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#configExternalized). You can set a absolute location or let Grails look into the classpath. Here's the example of the docs:

```
grails.config.locations = [
    "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
    "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
    "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy" ]
```

**EDIT**: I tested here. It appears that the value is only available throught the config object during runtime and not available inside Config.groovy. According to [this](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/using-an-external-property-w-in-Config-groovy-td3095970.html) thread it's not possible to do what you want.

Comment: How I can use it in my appender?

Comment: Like the example use "appName": ${myAppli.log.path}

Comment: Ok, when I print grails.config.locations I have correct result: path of  my properties file. Can I get my properties from grails.config.locations?
(${myAppli.log.path} doesn't work)

Comment: no, print {appName.log.path} ==> Config$_run_closure3@1b1e865

Answer (score 0):

You're almost right.  The `log4j` closure is executed after the whole configuration has been parsed and assembled, and within the closure you have access to the complete configuration via the variable `config`.  You can say

```
grails.config.locations = ['file:file.properties']

log4j = {
    appenders {
        file name:'myAppli', file:"${config.myAppli.log.path}myLogs.log"
    }
    // ...
}
```

I've tested this with Grails 2.2: run `grails create-app log4jtest` to create a new application, then edit `log4jtest/grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` to add at the top

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:file.properties"]
logfile.name = "from-config.log"
```

and for the `log4j` closure

```
// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    println "filename: ${config.logfile.name}"
    // rest of closure as before
```

Run this app using `grails run-app` and you'll see it print `filename: from-config.log` (twice, in fact).  Now create a file named `file.properties` in the top-level `log4jtest` folder containing the line

```
logfile.name=from-external.log
```

Run the app again and this time it will print `filename: from-external.log` instead.

Comment: grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["MYAPPLI_CONF_PATH"] print "${config.myAppli.log.path}" is wrang
System.properties["MYAPPLI_CONF_PATH"] = "path/file.prop"

Comment: @Valeri the `config` variable definitely works correctly _inside the log4j closure_ (though not elsewhere in Config.groovy).  Note that external configuration files named by `grails.config.locations` _must_ have names that end in either `.groovy` (if they're groovy files) or `.properties` (if they're property files) - `file.prop` will not work.